# Why print nltk.ConditionalFreqDist tabulate has None in output?

Tags: python, nltk, tabulate

Using Anaconda Spyder, Python 3.8.3, nltk 3.5.  The code and output below:

```
from nltk.corpus import reuters
cfd = [('gas', word) for word in brown.words(categories='gas')]
print(cfd.tabulate(conditions=['gas'], samples=['gasoline', 'barrels']))

----------------
Output:
    gasoline  barrels 
gas       77       64 
None
```

**How can I remove None from this output?**

> FYI - None is not in output when I use Jupyter notebook as below:

```
cfd = [('gas', word) for word in brown.words(categories='gas')]
cfd.tabulate(conditions=['gas'], samples=['gasoline', 'barrels']

----------------
Output:
    gasoline  barrels 
gas       77       64
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need print to display the output. Just use

```
cfd.tabulate(conditions=['gas'], samples=['gasoline', 'barrels'])
```